# Unable to run apps on Fedora 35 - libffmpeg.so: No such file or directory

Tags: fedora, ffmpeg

I'm trying to run apps such as [flipper](https://github.com/facebook/flipper) and [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) by downloading the bundled linux app. However, when I try to run those from the CLI, I get this error

```
:; ./react-native-debugger 
./react-native-debugger: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

```
:; ./flipper 
./flipper: error while loading shared libraries: libffmpeg.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried install `ffmpeg` package, but that doesn't seem to help

```
:; dnf list installed | grep ffmpeg
ffmpeg.x86_64                                     4.4.1-1.fc35                                    @rpmfusion-free-updates
ffmpeg-devel.x86_64                               4.4.1-1.fc35                                    @rpmfusion-free-updates
ffmpeg-libs.x86_64                                4.4.1-1.fc35                                    @rpmfusion-free-updates
```

Comment: I guess the `libffmpeg.so` that comes with "Flipper-linux.zip" https://fbflipper.com/ .... also can be used with your executable `flipper`.

Comment: Thanks. I must've extracted it wrong. Re-extracting the zip with the full content solved the problem. Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I must've extracted the bundle incorrectly. Re-extracting the zip with has libffmpeg.so file fixed it.